# UITableViewCell: image appears behind the Cell View

Tags: iphone, xcode, uitableview, uiimageview

its really annoying but for some reason my ImageView appears right behind the Cell View. If I turn clipping off then I can see the Image just right behind the cell. FYI, I am trying to display the image which was picked from the photo library and converted to PNG.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{

    static NSString *headerCellID = @"FormHeaderCellView";
    if(indexPath.section==0 && indexPath.row==0) //Header cell
    {
        FormHeaderCellView *cell = (FormHeaderCellView *)[self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:headerCellID];

        if (cell == nil)
        {
            NSArray *topLevelObjects =[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:headerCellID owner:nil options:nil];

            for (id currentObject in topLevelObjects) 
            {
                if( [currentObject isKindOfClass:[UITableViewCell class]])
                {
                    cell = (FormHeaderCellView *) currentObject;
                    break;
                }
            }

        }


        NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
        NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
        NSString *file = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"logo.png"];

        if([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:file])
        {   
            UIImage *img=[[UIImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:file];

            [cell.logoImage setImage:img];
        }


        [cell.textLabel setText:[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"userName"]];

        [cell setSelectionStyle:UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone];

        return cell;

    }
```

Everything seems to be loading just fine since I can visually see the image behind the cell.
Would appreciate your help.

**Update:** Did some tests and the image appears just fine if in the Nib I set 
logoImage's image property to any image in the bundle. So the problem is with displaying the image which is loaded from the documents directory (which was saved from photo library).

Comment: Where are you creating frame for: cell.logoImage ?

Comment: FormHeaderCellView is a subclass of UITableViewCell and logoImage is an IBOutlet UIImageView property. In the NIB i have hooked up the connections just fine.

Comment: In the NIB make sure that the logoImage is above everything else.

Comment: yes the logo image is on top.

Comment: I don't understand what you want to do and what you are getting, an image would be appreciated, if you are still interested in solving this.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have a Mac nearby, so I apologize for any errors in the code.

Are you sure that logoImage is above other views? In your cell class try to do the following:

```
[self.view addSubview:self.logoImage];
[self.view bringSubviewToFront:self.logoImage];
```

that should place your logoView on top of all other subviews of the cell.

Hope it helps